# LDA cross validation and variable selection

Tags: r, machine-learning, dataframe, cross-validation, lda

I have a data frame with 395 observations and 36 variables. I am doing cross validation to select the best few variables to classify the student qualifications. I have written this code:

```
k<-5
error <- c()
for(l in 1:35){
  if(l!=31 && l!=32 && l!=33){
    x<-0
    for (i in 1:k){
      train<-rep(TRUE, dim(student.mat)[1])
      for(j in 1:dim(student.mat)[1]/k){
        train[(i-1)*dim(student.mat)[1]/k+j]<-FALSE
      }
      test=!train
      student.test=student.mat[test,]
      student.train=student.mat[train,]
      nota3.test=nota3[test]
      lda.fit<-lda(nota3~student.mat[,i], data=student.mat, subset=train)
      lda.pred<-predict(lda.fit, student.test)
      table(lda.pred$class, nota3.test)
      y<-mean(lda.pred$class!=nota3.test)
      x<-x+y
      #cat("k = ", i, "error: ", y*100,"%", "\n")
    }
    #cat("Media del error = ", x/k*100,"%", "\n")
    error <- c(error, x/k)
  }else{
    error <- c(error, 100)
  }
}
error
names(student.mat)[which.max(error)]
```

and I get this error:

**Error in table(lda.pred$class, nota3.test) : 
  all arguments must have the same length
Also: lost warning messages
'newdata' had 79 rows but variables found have 395 rows**

but if I write the name of one variable of the data set instead of `student.mat[,i]`, it works.
The lda function don't read `student.mat[,i]` correctly.

Comment: There seems to be a rash of LDA questions involving R on SO lately. Is there a course that is assigning problems in classification?

Comment: it is a subject of my university degree

Answer (score 0):

You can create the formula programmatically:

```
lda.fit<-lda(paste0("nota3~", names(student.mat)[i]), data=student.mat, subset=train)
```

Comment: it doesn't work, i get this error: 

Error en lda.default(paste0("nota3~", names(student.mat)[i]), data = student.mat,  : 
  'x' is not a matrix